# I want to create http proxy server to serve login page with cookies in php

Tags: php, node.js, backend

I am trying to create a http proxy server on which someone vists my site a.com it shows the content of b.com/dashboard wothout changing url.
Note i want to bypass login by providing cookies . can anybody help me in it please

Comment: What's the point of the login, and the cookies, if you're going to bypass it anyway? This all sounds like a bad plan.

Comment: The whole scenario is i want my office worker to use my website domain link where they will not need to login from username password and my website serve them the subscription so that people accessing that subscription will not be able to get cookies of main site and access it from any other browser

Comment: if i make it simple than i am trying to make something like online vpn

Comment: An online VPN is not simple by any means. Anyway, given what you have, a website with a login, why don't you make the login cookie last longer than a browsing session? That way someone, who has logged in once, will be logged in the next time they visit the site.

Comment: i also want site b to look my session as loged in by only one ip address and all of my traffic are visiting that site from my site

Comment: Yes, I assumed as much. However, you're looking for complicated solutions, the best solution is the simplest one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248865/discussion-between-yousaf-raza-and-kiko-software).

Comment: Why is this tagged both PHP and Node.JS? Are you looking for a solution in any of these languages? Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i have tried to do in both language but doesn;t work

Comment: i have subscribed multiple accounts for a specific sites and i am managing my office but that site doesnt allow account sharing at all even they block if we change our network twice a day i have more than 50 people working in my place and all of them require it for specific task e.g if someone want to scan something and other want to search for some thing.

Comment: but i can only afford 5 to 10 subscriptions so if i buy for all the total usage will be only 1% of the total quota a subscription provides so everything else will be wasted. and i have many worker working remotely so i want to create a website on which if somebody browse it, it shows all the things and functionality of the other site. the benefits i will get is my all traffic will be passing through my vps so the ip address to that server will be single one so they will not block and my people will not share it to there friends as it will be password protected as well as single session site